# [iOS][ReactNative] Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 when building for Generic iOS Device with react-viro

Tags: ios, react-native

### Environment

1. Development OS: MacOS
2. Device OS & Version: Xcode 10.2.1 (10E1001)
3. Version: react-viro: 2.15.0 & react-native: 0.60.4

### Description

I cannot compile my application it throws this error:

```sh
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/loiclopez/app/node_modules/react-viro/ios/dist/ViroRenderer/static_lib/ViroKit_static_lib.framework/ViroKit_static_lib, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/loiclopez/app/node_modules/react-viro/ios/dist/ViroRenderer/static_lib/ViroKit_static_lib.framework/ViroKit_static_lib (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_VROViewAR", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libViroReact.a(VRTARSceneNavigator.o)
      objc-class-ref in libViroReact.a(VRTARUtils.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_VROViewControllerGVR", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libViroReact.a(VRTSceneNavigator.o)
      objc-class-ref in libViroReact.a(VRTVRSceneNavigator.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_VROViewScene", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libViroReact.a(VRT3DSceneNavigator.o)
  "getBlankTexture(VROTextureType)", referenced from:
      -[VRTMaterialManager loadVideoTextureForMaterial:driver:context:] in libViroReact.a(VRTMaterialManager.o)
      -[VRTMaterialVideo updateMaterialVideoTexture] in libViroReact.a(VRTMaterialVideo.o)
  "VROGeometryUtilGetPrimitiveCount(int, VROGeometryPrimitiveType)", referenced from:
      -[VRTGeometry updateGeometry] in libViroReact.a(VRTGeometry.o)
  "toDegrees(float)", referenced from:
      +[VRTARHitTestUtil rotationFromVector:] in libViroReact.a(VRTARHitTestUtil.o)
      ___49-[VRTNodeModule getNodeTransform:resolve:reject:]_block_invoke in libViroReact.a(VRTNodeModule.o)
      -[VRTScene cameraOrientation] in libViroReact.a(VRTScene.o)
      -[VRTScene logSceneDebugInfo:] in libViroReact.a(VRTScene.o)
      -[VRTNode onRotate:node:rotationRadians:rotateState:] in libViroReact.a(VRTNode.o)
      +[VRTARUtils createDictionaryFromAnchor:] in libViroReact.a(VRTARUtils.o)
  "toRadians(float)", referenced from:
      -[VRTNode setRotation:] in libViroReact.a(VRTNode.o)
      -[VRTCamera setRotation:] in libViroReact.a(VRTCamera.o)
      -[VRT360Video setRotation:] in libViroReact.a(VRT360Video.o)
      -[VRT360Video updateSceneWithSphereTexture] in libViroReact.a(VRT360Video.o)
      -[VRT360Image setRotation:] in libViroReact.a(VRT360Image.o)
      -[VRT360Image updateSceneWithSphereTexture] in libViroReact.a(VRT360Image.o)
      ___56-[VRTARSceneNavigatorModule setWorldOrigin:worldOrigin:]_block_invoke in libViroReact.a(VRTARSceneNavigatorModule.o)

  // and more errors...
```

**This issue only occurs when archiving for a release or build for Generic iOS Device.**